# Fastest way to find a minimum amount of sets from a set of sets that has the largest union?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, set

Given a set of unique sets, I want to find a minimum amount of sets that has the largest union, i.e., the universe. As an example, let's say we have a set of 20 random sets of integers with different sizes ranging from 1 to 10:

```
import random

random.seed(99)
length = 20
ss = {frozenset(random.sample(range(100), random.randint(1,10))) for _ in range(length)}
assert len(ss) == 20 # This might be smaller than 20 if frozensets are not all unique
```

The largest union (universe) is given by

```
universe = frozenset().union(*ss)
print(universe)

# frozenset({0, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 
#            26, 27, 29, 31, 32, 34, 37, 39, 40, 42, 43, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 
#            51, 52, 53, 54, 56, 59, 60, 62, 63, 64, 66, 67, 68, 69, 75, 76, 
#            77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 84, 86, 87, 88, 89, 91, 92, 93, 95, 97, 98, 99})
```

Right now I am using a brute-force method to search from the unions of 1 to 20 subsets using `itertools.combinations`. As shown below, the code finds a minimum amount of 17 subsets after 2.95 s.

```
from itertools import combinations
from time import time

t0 = time()
n = 1
res = []
found = False
while not found:
    # Get all combinations of n subsets
    all_n_ss = list(combinations(ss, n))
    for n_ss in all_n_ss:
        u = frozenset().union(*n_ss)
        if u == universe:
            res = n_ss
            found = True
            break
    # Add one more subset
    n += 1

print(len(res))
print(res)
print(time()-t0)

# 17
# (frozenset({0, 66, 7, 42, 48, 17, 81, 51, 25, 27}), 
#  frozenset({49, 27, 87, 47}), 
#  frozenset({76, 48, 17, 22, 25, 29, 31}), 
#  frozenset({14}), 
#  frozenset({0, 66, 68, 10, 46, 54, 25, 26, 59}), 
#  frozenset({75, 92, 53, 78}), 
#  frozenset({67, 68, 11, 79, 87, 89, 62}), 
#  frozenset({67, 99, 40, 10, 43, 11, 51, 86, 91, 60}), 
#  frozenset({6, 59, 91, 76, 45, 16, 20, 56, 27, 95}), 
#  frozenset({32, 98, 40, 46, 15, 86, 23, 29, 63}), 
#  frozenset({99, 37, 12, 77, 15, 18, 19, 52, 22, 95}), 
#  frozenset({39, 10, 11, 80, 18, 53, 54, 87}), 
#  frozenset({32, 93}), 
#  frozenset({34}), 
#  frozenset({64, 84, 22}), 
#  frozenset({32, 97, 69, 45, 16, 51, 88, 60}), 
#  frozenset({21}))
# 2.9506494998931885
```

However, in reality I have a set of 200 sets, which is infeasible for a brute-froce enumeration. I want a fast algorithm to find just **one** **optimal** solution.

Comment: This is a well-known problem called [the set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).  It's an NP-complete problem, so there is no known fast solution.  However, there are approximate solutions with more reasonable runtime performance, such as [the greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm).

Comment: I would suggest the following:
1. sort the sets by length
2. Loop through the list of sets. If a set is a subset of the union of all the rest sets, then remove it from the list. If not then remove it from the list and add it to the result list

Comment: You could try a greedy method. 1) Find every unique number by iterating over each distinct set. 2) For every number, you found in step 1, find which subsets contain the respective number. 3) Sort those appearance lists, e.g., if a number appeared in only 1 subset, it should be at the top. 4) Use a greedy approach to pick a subset for the top number such that this subset contributes most compared to other subsets which contain the respective number. Then do the same thing (step 4) for the next top number.

Comment: @TomKarzes no known fast solution *in the worst case*, which is an important detail. The code below can find and prove the optimal solution for a 200-set instance in under 3 seconds on my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer program solvers are pretty good at this. Sample code in OR-Tools (`pip install ortools`):

```py
import collections
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp


def set_cover(ss):
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver("SCIP")
    solver.Objective().SetMinimization()
    constraints = collections.defaultdict(
        lambda: solver.Constraint(1, solver.infinity())
    )
    variables = []
    for s in ss:
        x = solver.BoolVar(str(s))
        solver.Objective().SetCoefficient(x, 1)
        for e in s:
            constraints[e].SetCoefficient(x, 1)
        variables.append((s, x))
    status = solver.Solve()
    assert status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL
    return {s for (s, x) in variables if x.solution_value()}


import random


def main():
    random.seed(99)
    length = 200
    ss = {
        frozenset(random.sample(range(100), random.randint(1, 10)))
        for _ in range(length)
    }
    print(set_cover(ss))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```